# Is there a basic mathematical relationship between IQ and learning speed?

Tags: performance, iq

Is there a basic mathematical relationship between IQ and learning speed? ... such as linear, exponential, etc?

For example, if some number of people with an approximate IQ of 100 (95-105) take X minutes to complete a task (lets also say plus-minus 5%), is there an expected average Y time people with an average 120 would need?

Can you cite the research?

Comment: This question is effectively a duplicate of [Does IQ affect learning speed?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/36/does-iq-affect-learning-speed)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, wouldn't the answer be yes?, what other purpose does IQ serve? It's like asking if water effects rain. 

I am very clearly asking for the relationship between the two. I'm really thrown for a loop when people make these kinds of equivocations.

Comment: IQ was originally defined by expressing mental age as a percentage of chronological age, which is close to what you have in mind (although learning isn't the same thing as general cognitive ability). However, the modern deviation-based definition doesn't have that feature.